# Lorentz contraction possibility arguments in transverse and longitudinal directions

Tags: special-relativity

I have read an argument for the impossibility of transverse longitudinal contraction in several places. For instance, Feynman say:

> How do we know that perpendicular lengths do not change? The men can agree to make marks on each other’s y-meter stick as they pass each other. By symmetry, the two marks must come at the same y- and y′-coordinates, since otherwise, when they get together to compare results, one mark will be above or below the other, and so we could tell who was really moving.

**Question:** The problem now is that I don't see why a modified version of this argument won't also apply to length contraction. Suppose we make two copies of a L shaped rod with one mark on the horizontal arm at the end and give one to the person in the train and the other to the person on the station.

We give the person in the train instructions to make a mark on the horizontal arm of the L of the person in the station corresponding to his own mark as they align the vertical portions of their rods when the train passes by.

Then, the person inside the train will see the rod in the station shrunk along the horizontal direction and therefore his new mark will be towards the edge of the L rod.

On the other hand, the person on the station will see the contraction in the train guy's rod and the new mark will be towards the center of the L rod.

### Contradiction!

I hope the question was coherent. What am I doing wrong?